# Timer and TimerTask - how to reschedule Timer from within TimerTask run

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, timertask

basically what I want to do is to make a Timer that runs a specific TimerTask after x seconds, but then the TimerTask can reschedule the Timer to do the task after y seconds. Example is below, it gives me an error "Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task already scheduled or cancelled" on line where I try to schedule this task in TimerTask run.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class JavaReminder {

    public JavaReminder(int seconds) {
        Timer timer = new Timer();  
        timer.schedule(new RemindTask(timer, seconds), seconds*2000);
    }

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
        Timer timer;
        int seconds;
        RemindTask(Timer currentTimer, int sec){
            timer = currentTimer;
            seconds = sec;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("ReminderTask is completed by Java timer");
            timer = new Timer(); 
            timer.schedule(this, seconds*200);
            System.out.println("scheduled");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Java timer is about to start");
        JavaReminder reminderBeep = new JavaReminder(2);
        System.out.println("Remindertask is scheduled with Java timer.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you writing the same line again in run() method?

            timer = new Timer(); 
            timer.schedule(this, seconds*200);

As you are already scheduled your task in constructor that why you are getting java.lang.IllegalStateException.

Remove these lines and run it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use new `RemindTask` instead of existing one.

It should be

```
timer.schedule(new RemindTask(timer, seconds), seconds*200);
```

instead of

```
timer.schedule(this, seconds*200);
```

Comment: @Braj  If it is executed for a long time, is it cause for a memory leak?