# Java - change the duration of Timer while it is running

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have a `Timer` that I scheduled a `TimerTask` with the `delay` 0 and the `period` 150.
Now I want to change the `period`, but the `Timer` is already running.
How can I change the `period` now?

```
private int penultimateStep = 1;
private int lastStep = 1;
private Timer move = new Timer();
private TimerTask movePlayer = new TimerTask(){
    public void run(){
        //Schritte ändern
        if(lastStep==3){
            lastStep = 2;
            penultimateStep = 1;
        }
        else if(lastStep==1){
            lastStep = 2;
            penultimateStep = 3;
        }
        else if(lastStep==2){
            if(penultimateStep==1){
                lastStep = 1;
                penultimateStep = 3;
            }
            else if(penultimateStep==3){
                lastStep = 3;
                penultimateStep = 1;
            }
        }
    }
};


...

move.schedule(movePlayer, 0, 150);
```

Comment: Can you share some code to help ?

Comment: Depends on what timer you're using.

Comment: you want to reschedule the task?

Comment: post an [MCVE] please

Comment: https://hastebin.com/xemucaxaru.cs

I want to change the speed of 150 to 200 (for example) while the timer is running

Answer (score -1):

[Timer and TimerTask - how to reschedule Timer from within TimerTask run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25001052/timer-and-timertask-how-to-reschedule-timer-from-within-timertask-run)

[Resettable Java Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001/resettable-java-timer)

Check the two links. This question might be a duplicate of either of the above.

So you can modify your code as follows:

```
private int penultimateStep = 1;
private int lastStep = 1;
private Timer move = new Timer();

class MovePlayer extends TimerTask {
   public void run(){
       //Schritte ändern
       if(lastStep==3){
           lastStep = 2;
           penultimateStep = 1;
        }
        else if(lastStep==1){
            lastStep = 2;
            penultimateStep = 3;
        }
        else if(lastStep==2){
            if(penultimateStep==1){
                lastStep = 1;
                penultimateStep = 3;
            }
            else if(penultimateStep==3){
                lastStep = 3;
                penultimateStep = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}


...

move.schedule(new MovePlayer(), 0, 150);
```

Cheers.